# Custom fields mapping

Tags: odoo

I added some custom fields to model `crm.lead` and to model `res.partner`.

When I convert lead to opportunity, odoo creates customer and I want the customer to have custom fields with values from lead.

How can I do this?

Comment: please show your effects and some code what have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi! I redefined method _lead_create_contact in class crm_lead (crm_lead.py). Here is the code: http://pastebin.com/FuLKnx5M, but it does'nt work. Can you help me?

Comment: Was there any resolution to this? I'm new to Odoo as well and trying to extend leads and partners as well. The pastebin is helpful, just not sure where to put that class in my custom module